# a LaTeX package to set Diplomacy games?

Tags: chessboard, sudoku

Does anyone know of any efforts to develop a package to typeset games of [Diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_(game)), or anyone who might be interested in working on such?

Something that could set a board position (e.g. Armies and Fleets on the map) would be great.  Updating board positions would be unrealistic as it would require adjudication - which is [deep water](http://web.inter.nl.net/users/L.B.Kruijswijk/).

We've just started a [project](https://github.com/rowatc/Diplomacy-AI/blob/master/README.md) to build an AI to play Diplomacy, and it would be nice to be able to properly typeset positions.

Comment: Can you please add a short summary of the games/what you are expecting? I just feel too lazy to read the whole Wikipedia page.

Comment: It sounds as though you want to typeset an annotated map of Europe with portions of Western Asia and North Africa like the illustration in the Wikipedia reference, or is it more that that?.

Comment: Yes: a cartoon map divided into the 75 Diplomacy provinces, on top of which appropriately coloured Army/Fleet markers can be placed.